# joinWithCassandraTable getting much slower on growing table size

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm currently using this stack:

- Cassandra 2.2 (multinode)
- Spark/Streaming 1.4.1
- Spark-Cassandra-Connector 1.4.0-M3

I've got this DStream[Ids] with RDDs counting around 6000-7000 elements. `id` is the Partition Key.

```
val ids: DStream[Ids] = ...
ids.joinWithCassandraTable(keyspace, tableName, joinColumns = SomeColumns("id"))
```

As `tableName` gets bigger, let's say around 30k "rows", the query takes much longer, and I'm having trouble staying under the batch duration threshold. It performs similarly to using a massive `IN`-clause, which I've understood is not advisable.

Are there more effective ways to do this?

Answer:
Always remember to repartition your local RDDs with `repartitionByCassandraReplica` before doing joins with Cassandra to ensure that each partition is only working against the local Cassandra node. In my case, I also had to ramp up the partitions on the joining local RDD/DStream in order for the tasks to spread evenly across workers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is "id" a partition key in your table?  If not, I think it needs to be, otherwise you may be doing a table scan which would run progressively slower as the table gets bigger.

Also to get good performance with this method I believe you need to use the repartitionByCassandraReplica() operation on your ids RDD so that the joins are a local operation on each node.

See [this](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#repartitioning-rdds-based-on-a-cassandra-tables-replication).

Comment: Indeed, it's way faster now. I'm doing `repartitionByCassandraReplica(keyspace, tableName)` with 10 partitions as default. I only have 2 executors and the data is being partitioned with Murmur3. It seems though, that only one worker is reading data, which leads to the other one being idle. Is this a partitioning issue?

Comment: Do you only have one node?  Usually you would have one spark worker running on each node, so each worker would load the data that is local to that node.

Comment: No, I have one driver and 2 executors, on 3 machines. I would think that even with the default of 10 partitions, it would try to spread stuff around.

Comment: If you have three nodes, then you'll want to have three executors, otherwise some of the data will need to be shuffled over the network, which will slow things down.  If you're looking for the fastest performance, you want to keep all operations local to each node.

Comment: Uhm, yes. The driver is an executor. What I meant is that I have 2 workers, 3 executors and 3 machines. I'm really not struggling with shuffling. Anyways, I cranked up the partitions on the input DStream to `repartitionByCassandraReplica` and it seemed to distribute work evenly to the other worker. Now I just need to optimize partitions, but that's for another thread.